# Databricks Error when Loading data to Synapse: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column number mismatch

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, aws-databricks

```
Exception encountered in Azure Synapse Analytics connector code
```

Databricks to Synapse data load error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column number mismatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databricks uses a spark driver to connect to synapse, it check the number of columns, name, column order between azure synapse table (if it is for an existing table) and spark datafarme. if it is not matching it will throw error.

```
 com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWConnectorException: Exception encountered in Azure Synapse Analytics connector code ..........
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column number mismatch
```